# How to combine 5 matrices in c++/opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 5 mxn matrices.. first I converted them to 1 row matrices using the following code:

```
//now converting to 1 row matrix
CvMat row_header, *row;
row = cvReshape(mat, &row_header, 0, 1)
```

is this correct?

then suppose I have 5 such matrices (1 row and 50 columns) how do I combine them into a big matrix (5 rows and 50 columns)?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, **learn the C++ API of OpenCV**.

Then do sth. like this:

```
cv::Mat dest(number_of_rows, number_of_columns);
row1.copyTo(dest.row(1));
row2.copyTo(dest.row(2));
...
```

Source: http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat_#mat-row

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation I did go through it and I have some questions and would appreciate if someone could answer them. 

so I have 5 - 1 row matrices (suppose they are x = [1,2,3] y = [4,5,6]...), and I want to combine them, for this I will create another matrix.
`M1 = cvCreateMat(5,50,CV_32FC1); 
Mat M1 = x.row(1); 
Mat M1 = y.row(1); 
.
.
.`
so umm?? will this work? this is what I picked up from the link but i dont think I fully understand it, like everytime I say Mat M1 = z.row(1); so will the old data be overwritten or will a new row be created?

Comment: I have edited my question with the updated code, can you please look at it. Thanks

Comment: the copyto method does not work, as except for my M1 matrix all other are of type cvArr.. and .row does not work on cvArr.

Comment: That's why I said: *Learn the c++ API of OpenCV*. I cannot give advice on the C API. If you don't want to learn it, then remove the C++ tag from your question, add the C tag and you will get C answers.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I fixed it with the following code:

```
CvMat *M1;
    //cv::Mat M1(2,row->width,CV_32FC1);
    M1 = cvCreateMat(5,row->width,CV_32FC1 );
    //row.copyTo(M1.row(0));
    //row2.copyTo(M1.row(2));
    //M1.row(0) = 0;
    //M1.row(0) = row + 0;
    //M1.row(1) = 0;
    //M1.row(1) = row2 + 0;
    cvSetZero(M1);

    /*for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<row->width;j++)
        {
            CV_MAT_ELEM( *M1, float, i, j ) = CV_MAT_ELEM( *rowi, float, 0, i );*/

    for(int i=0;i<row->width;i++)
    {
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *M1, float, 0, i ) = CV_MAT_ELEM( *row, float, 0, i );
    }

    for(int j=0;j<row2->width;j++)
    {
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *M1, float, 1, j ) = CV_MAT_ELEM( *row2, float, 0, j );
    }
    for(int k=0;k<row2->width;k++)
    {
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *M1, float, 2, k ) = CV_MAT_ELEM( *row3, float, 0, k );
    }
    for(int l=0;l<row2->width;l++)
    {
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *M1, float, 3, l ) = CV_MAT_ELEM( *row3, float, 0, l );
    }
    for(int m=0;m<row2->width;m++)
    {
        CV_MAT_ELEM( *M1, float, 4, m ) = CV_MAT_ELEM( *row4, float, 0, m );
    }
```

the matrix M1 is a 5 row matrix having 50 columns.. each row represents a separate matrix.. row, row2, row3, row4 and row5